# Launch thread, do work, close app, continue to do work in background in other thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to fulfil some needs for my users and one of them is proving a bit difficult. I can't create a Windows Service to do this, and so I'm not sure how else to do it.

Basically, they keep closing the program after *they* are done with it. But the application clearly indicates that an operation is still in progress and that they must wait for they close the window. There's no need for an ETA on this operation, and since they insist on closing the app before it's had its chance to do *their* work, I thought of something.

How can I close an app (*not* `this.Hide()` - but `this.Dispose(true)`) but launch an external thread that runs an operation while the app has been closed?

Comment: Is hiding the UI really that bad? It would give them the impression it has finished. Why are they closing it when it's still working? Seems quite odd.

Comment: Why dont you disable the exit button while the operation is executing?

Comment: They're closing it when it's still not finished because they're idiots, like I keep telling them. Second, hiding it is a terrible idea! They called me incompetent for suggesting that!

Comment: I can do that, but I'm not in the business of pissing people off unfortunately. These guys, they're like full OCD about certain things. Like monitoring usage and system resources and stuff - I still don't understand but I figured if there is a way to do this, it would be the easiest way and would keep us both happy.

Comment: You cannot start a thread to do this, but you could start another process.

Comment: @juharr Oh I should've thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't a system-resources-aware OCD guy be even more pissed if there was a hidden process running, compared to having a tray icon indicating that it's actually running? It seems like cheating to "hide" this, I doubt that it would make them any happier.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of apps get "closed to tray", i.e. simply hidden, there is nothing unusual with that. I would suggest to your client that this is a common approach, *if* you want to keep the app running. Creating a new (hidden) process to do this is just doing this same thing, only more error prone, harder to do properly and harder to monitor.

Also, having a "hidden" process working in the background could likely cause issues if your client decides to start your app again while the background job is still active. But if the app has work to do, I don't see why you couldn't prevent closing it. That's the best way, because you can ensure that there's only one instance running and be able to monitor its progress properly.

If they are forcefully closing it (e.g. using Task Manager), then there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is once you close the app you also dispose all of its children, you either need to do the this.hide() then call application.exit() once your work is complete, or create a new top level application that launches the main UI app and handles the background work.

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the `FormClosing` event and cancel attempts to close the app until the process is complete and you're ready to allow it.

```
private bool isProcessRunning;

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = isProcessRunning;
}
```

Set `isProcessRunning` to `True` before you start the thread; set it to `False` when you're finished.

I'd also consider displaying an indicator that the process is still running (like a `ProgressBar`), so they don't sit there trying to close the app, thinking it's simply unresponsive.

Of course, if the process is really important you might want a more robust solution. Can't stop the user from just shutting down their machine, which would also kill your process.

Answer (score 0):

Before I give my solution, permit me to say that I don't think you should do this.  Instead, hide the window, or minimize to the tray, or something like that.  I think this is what users expect.  Lots of applications minimize and continue doing work then exit when they are done.  If the app looks like it has exited, but is really still running, the user might reboot, or launch the application again.

If you really do want to do this, either:

1) Do the work in another thread.  The EXE will not exit until the thread completes.  Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   new Thread(DoWork).Start();
} 
private void DoWork()
{
   Thread.Sleep(10000);
   MessageBox.Show("done!");
}
```

2) Or do the work after the form exits.  Do this by modifying the Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());

    MessageBox.Show("Still running!  Can still do work here!");
}
```